# How to handle eager loading on REST API

Tags: php, angularjs, rest, laravel-5

Imagine you have the following resources for example: **Users**, **Posts** and **Comments** (With typical relationship setup in laravel).

When fetching a single Post, you will have the following endpoint

*GET /api/posts/1*

```
// With route model binding
public function show(Post $post)
{
   return $post;
}
```

This is fine if I only want the Post object, but in some pages in my application, I also need to load the **User** and the **Comments** associated with the Post.

How do you guys handle that kind of scenario?

**1.** Should I load everything in that endpoint like:

```
return $post->load(['user', 'comments.user']);
```

and call it a day? (nope)

**2.** Should I accept an additional parameter that will tell my controller to load the relationship based on that value?

```
// With route model binding
public function show(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    // rel for "relationship"
    if ($request->has('rel')) {
        $post->load($request->input('rel'));
    }

     return $post;
}
```

with this approach I could do something like this:
*GET /api/posts/1?rel=user*
returns Post with User

or I could build an array of parameter with jquery's $.param(['user', 'comments.user'])

*GET /api/posts/1?rel%5B%5D=user&rel%5B%5D=comments.user*
returns Post with User + Comments.User

but anyone can easily mess with the 'rel' parameter so I also need to check that
¯\(°_o)/¯

**3.** Just create a new endpoint for every specific requirements. (what should your endpoint look like for the example above?).

---

I'm building a SPA with Angular + Laravel (just a self-consumed API) for my Internal Project when I encounter this pitfall. The second approach is what I currently using for basic fetching and I use the third approach for more complex requirements.

Any inputs are appreciated.